# Nginx compiled --with-http_spdy_module yet raise errors complains ngx_http_spdy_module

Tags: nginx, spdy

```
[emerg] 21101#0: the "spdy" parameter requires ngx_http_spdy_module in /etc/nginx/conf.d/cc.conf
```

isn't it the same module?
and it causes multi-redirection error too. I have no idea what is going on.

Full configure arg:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.2
built by gcc 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module `--with-http_spdy_module` --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.1e
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no magic in the world, the most resonable explanation that you have two different nginx binaries in your system: one that you're trying to run, and the second one that you just have compiled.